# Show that $\Phi$ is not a contraction, but $\Phi \circ \Phi$ is a contraction

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, banach-spaces

> Consider $V = C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ with the norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{\infty}$. Define the application $\Phi: V \to V$ by 
>   $$\Phi(f)(x) = 1 + \int_{0}^{x}f(\tau)\operatorname{d}\tau.$$
>   (a) Show that $\Phi$ is not a contraction, but $\Phi \circ \Phi$ is a contraction
>
> (b) Show that $\Phi$ has a unique fixed point in $V$.

I have an idea how to prove item (b). Actually, I proved in a previous question that if $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is such that $f^{k} = f \circ ... \circ f$ is a contraction, then $f$ has a unique fixed points and I don't remember using that $\dim \mathbb{R}^{n} = n$.

For item (a), I think I didn't understand the function, maybe it's a notation problem. For show that $\Phi$ is not a contraction is sufficient to find a function $f$ such that $\max f > 1$, because $\Vert \Phi'\Vert_{\infty} = \Vert f \Vert_{\infty}$? Now, I was very confused about $\Phi \circ \Phi$. How is that composition?

Comment: What are you stuck on in part (b)? It's just a matter of writing down the fixed points.

Comment: $$\Phi \circ \Phi (f)(\cdot) = 1 + \int_0^{(\cdot)} \left[ 1 + \int_0^\tau f(t) \, \mathrm d t \right] \, \mathrm d \tau$$

Comment: @anomaly, I don't need help in item (b). I just wanted to understand item (a).

Comment: To show that $\Phi$ is not a contraction, you need to find $f,g \in V$ such that $$ \| \Phi(f) - \Phi(g) \| \ge \| f - g \|. $$

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist, a criterion for classifying contractions $f$ is not to check whether $|f'| < 1$?

Comment: To show that it is not a contraction you need to show that $\sup_{f \neq g} {\|\Phi(f)-\Phi(g)\| \over \| f-g\|} \ge 1$.

Comment: "I think I didn't understand the function" I think that's the point. $\Phi$ maps functions to functions. So, forget about derivatives. For each function $f\in V$, $\Phi(f)$ is a function in $V$, namely that one that maps each $x\in [0,1]$ to $1+\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$.

Comment: Does "contraction" mean "strict contraction" here?

Comment: @amsmath, sure! Now I see! Thank you!

Comment: @amsmath, yes! Need to be strict

Comment: Just to be sure: (b) is simple. Let $f$ be the unique fixed point of $\Phi\circ\Phi$. Then also $g := \Phi(f)$ is a fixed point of $\Phi\circ\Phi$ because $\Phi(\Phi(g)) = \Phi(\Phi(\Phi(f))) = \Phi(f) = g$. But as $f$ was unique, it follows that $g=f$, i.e., $\Phi(f) = g = f$.

Comment: @amsmath, yes! I had done this in the case in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that I said, I just was not sure if it would be worth in an infinite dimension space, but in this idea I don't seem to need the dimension.

Comment: Note that since $\Phi$ is affine, showing that it is a contraction is equivalent to showing that $\| \Phi' \| < 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f=1, g=0$. Then $\phi(f)(x) = 1+x$, $\phi(g)(x) = 1$ and so $\|\Phi(f)-\Phi(g)\| = 1$ and $\|f-g\| = 1$.

$\phi^2(f)(x) = 1+ \int_0^x \Phi(f)(t) dt= 1 + x + \int_0^x \int_0^t f(s) ds dt$.

Hence $\phi^2(f)(x) - \phi^2(g)(x) = \int_0^x \int_0^t (f(s) -g(s)) ds dt$ and
so
$\|\phi^2(f)(x) - \phi^2(g)(x) \| \le \int_0^x \int_0^t ds dt \|f-g\| = {x \over 2} \|f-g\|$.

If $\Phi^m$ has a unique fixed point then so does $\Phi$.
To see why, suppose $\Phi(x) = x$, then $\Phi^m(x) = x$ and hence $\Phi$ has
at most one fixed point. For existence, suppose $\Phi^m(x) = x$. Consider the
sequence $x, \Phi(x), \Phi^2(x), \Phi^{m-1}(x)$. Note that each of these points
is a fixed point of $\Phi^m$ and hence $\Phi^k(x) = x$ for all $k$.

**Aside**: When proving the Picard iteration theorem for ODEs, there are two broad approaches: (i) Choose a small enough interval so that $\Phi$ is a contraction
on that interval. (ii) Iterate $\Phi$ enough times so that $\Phi^m$ is a
contraction.